# .htaccess subdomain traffic to folder and sub folders

Tags: .htaccess

Ok long story short:

http://subdomain.domain.com/test1/test2
needs to display the information here:
http://domain.com/agents/subdomain/test1/test2

and obviously if you with this
http://subdomain.domain.com/
needs to display
http://domain.com/agents/subdomain/

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/agents
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /agents/%1/$1/ [L]
```

I need the first rule to get rid of the index.php from the URL.

I can get the first piece done http://subdomain.domain.com/  but not the sub folders.

the above syntax is throwing an internal server error but if I change the last line to:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /agents/%1/$1/ [L]
```

it works except I can't get to sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally figured this out... here's the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)? domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)? domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+)\. domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /index.php?/agents/%1/$1 [L]
```